# Call to 'AnsiReplaceStr' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, embarcadero

Após trocar o RAD Studio XE8 para o RAD Studio 10 Seattle obtive o seguinte erro:

```
[bcc64 Error] Unit1.cpp(425): call to 'AnsiReplaceStr' is ambiguous
System.StrUtils.hpp(51): candidate function
System.AnsiStrings.hpp(82): candidate function
```

Código original:

```
UniTable1->FieldByName("chuva")->AsFloat =
                StrToFloat(chuva, ".", ",");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi informando a função que estou utilizando `AnsiString`

Código alterado:

```
UniTable1->FieldByName("chuva")->AsFloat =
                StrToFloat(AnsiString(chuva), ".", ",");
```